# Is it possible to get same component data properties when i came back to the same URL through back button in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Actually in current page, I am changing the properties of component through some Drop-down,buttons and sliders.Then after i go to some other pages.Again after coming to the same page through back buttons,the page is loading freshly.so i want the page with previous settings.I tried with Param but its making my URL lengthy(have so many properties) as i have to set every property as a param.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to store your data so your page can read that data whenever the user enters the page a second time.

Comment: But the page should be loaded freshly whenever the user visited the same page not through back buttons.Is it possible to know that he came to the page through back button  ?

Comment: If the user clicked on the back button and moves to a different page, this page and all of its components will be rendered fresh. Your component just has to load the data from the store so you can display the previous settings